# I want to know the name of JAR file which is required to run javascript and HTML in android

Tags: javascript, android, html

Going in bit details... These are the packages which I want to import for linking android with  HTML and javascript.

```
import com.pfizer.android.R;
import com.pfizer.android.utils.DateUtils;
import com.pfizer.android.view.screens.journal.CreateEntryScreen;
```

Since the required jar file is not there so the aforementioned three import lines are giving me an error...So I wanted to know what is the name of that JAR File which i need to include in library for supplying these packages..

Comment: Where did you find out about those classes? Based on the class names, those look like proprietary code owned by Pfizer.

Comment: @Pointy, I searched it on google could not find it..Do you have any alterntatives...?